# advanced home routers for filtering internet activity

Tags: router, internet-filter

Are there any 'advanced' routers that would do things like:

1. store all urls visited or attempted to access on computers connected to the router?
2. block certain urls
3. whitelist urls

Does this exist or does one have to create a dedicated computer (prob. running linux) to do this?

Answer (score 2):

you're looking for an enterprise router, much cheaper to setup a spare box with **[Vyatta](http://www.vyatta.org/)**.

> The **Vyatta Community Edition** (VC)
>   is award-winning, Linux-based, open
>   source software providing routing,
>   firewalling, VPN, intrusion
>   prevention, and WAN load balancing
>   services, among others, for your
>   network. When you run Vyatta on a
>   standard x86 hardware system, you'll
>   create a powerful network appliance
>   that can run circles around
>   proprietary systems. Vyatta also runs
>   virtualized in VMware, Xen, Hyper-V,
>   and other hypervisors, providing
>   networking and security services to
>   virtual machines.

Answer (score 0):

a router with SYSLOG (system log) feature can "*store all urls visited or attempted to access on computers connected to the router*"

and most routers come with a firewall witch you can configure to filter traffics to/from some IP addresses. or using [OpenDNS](http://www.opendns.com/) for that.